# How to Use Group By and Sum in an Esqueleto Query

Tags: haskell, yesod, esqueleto

I am trying to use one of the example queries from Esqueleto but I cannot get it to compile. The only variation is that I am using it without a join.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
sqlite> select * from my_table;
id|category|amount
1|A|1.0
2|A|2.0
3|B|2.0
4|B|8.0
```

And I would like to do this:

```
select category,sum(amount) from my_table group by category;
category|sum(amount)
A|3.0
B|10.0
```

This is my query:

```
import qualified Database.Esqueleto as E

r <- runDB $
    E.select $ E.from $ \t  -> do
        E.groupBy $ t E.^. MyTableCategory
        let sum' = E.sum_ (t E.^. MyTableAmount)
        E.orderBy [E.desc sum']
        return (t E.^. MyTableCategory, sum' )
```

I get this error:

```
No instance for (PersistField b0) arising from a use of `E.select'
The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance PersistField Account -- Defined in `Model'
  instance PersistField AccountCategory -- Defined in `Model'
  instance PersistField MyTable -- Defined in `Model'
  ...plus 37 others
In the expression: E.select
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `E.select
   $ E.from
     $ \ t
         -> do { E.groupBy $ t E.^. MyTableCategory;
                 let ...;
                 .... }'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  r <- runDB
       $ E.select
         $ E.from
           $ \ t
               -> do { E.groupBy $ t E.^. MyTableCategory;
                       let ...;
                       .... }
```

Where do I provide the type information for `E.select`? Should the compiler be able to infer from `t E.^.MyTableCategory`? I also tried using the `countRows / groupBy` example here (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-1.4.1/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html) but similar issue (the only difference is that I don't have a join)

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your *models* entity listing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *from* table parameters types are sometimes deduced from the result type which must be explicit.

Other ambiguities arise about the monad type usually.

It is useful to enclose the query in a specific function to solve some ambiguities.

I cannot certify your *esqueleto* query conformity now but

Try this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports, ConstraintKinds #-}

import Import
import "esqueleto" Database.Esqueleto as E
import "monad-logger" Control.Monad.Logger (MonadLogger)
import "resourcet" Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadResourceBase)

type TCategory = Text  -- change it if its different
type TAmount = Double

myQuery :: (PersistQuery (SqlPersist m), MonadLogger m , MonadResourceBase m) =>

                        SqlPersist m [(E.Value TCategory, E.Value (Maybe TAmount))] -- corrected
myQuery = do

  -- your query

  E.select $ E.from $ \t  -> do
        E.groupBy $ t E.^. MyTableCategory
        let sum' = E.sum_ (t E.^. MyTableAmount)  
        E.orderBy [E.desc sum']
        return (t E.^. MyTableCategory, sum' )  

-- within your handler:

    pairListResult <- runDB myQuery

    forM_ pairListResult $ \(E.Value categ, E.Value maybeAmount) -> do -- whatever
```

Update: it compiles

Comment: Thank you very much @gabriel. Your previous version with extra type annotations (on t) still did not compile but this one does! I am not sure why giving the compiler more information is a bad thing :) Btw, it looks like `SqlPersist` is deprecated so it switched to `SqlPersistT` and that also works. Thanks again; I would not have figured this out on my own